# Alljoyn Cross compilation: Scons returns of non-existent variable ''alljoyn_jar''

Tags: java, cross-compiling, scons, alljoyn

Scons returns with an ERROR: scons: *** Return of non-existent variable ''alljoyn_jar''

the command is:

```
scons BINDINGS=java OS=openwrt CPU=openwrt VARIANT=debug BUILD_SERVICES_SAMPLES=off POLICYDB=on WS=off
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Building bindings: java
Building services: 
BULLSEYE_BIN not specified
Using OpenSSL crypto
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping common unit test build
BULLSEYE_BIN not specified
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping About Service unit test build
GTEST_DIR not specified skipping alljoyn_core unit test build

scons: *** Return of non-existent variable ''alljoyn_jar''
File "/home/pi/WORKING_DIRECTORY32/alljoyn-15.04.00-src/alljoyn_java/src/SConscript", line 48, in <module>

environment variable:

export CROSS_COMPILE_HOME=/opt/windriver/wrlinux/7.0-intel-quark/sysroots/quark-wrs-linux
export TARGET_PATH=$PATH
export TARGET_CC=gcc
export TARGET_CXX=g++
export TARGET_LINK=gcc
export TARGET_AR=ar
export TARGET_RANLIB=ranlib
export TARGET_CFLAGS="-I$CROSS_COMPILE_HOME/usr/lib/gcc/i586-windriverquark-linux/4.9.1/include -I$CROSS_COMPILE_HOME/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_79/include/"
export TARGET_CPPFLAGS=-I$CROSS_COMPILE_HOME/usr/lib/gcc/i586-windriverquark-linux/4.9.1/include
export TARGET_LDFLAGS=-L$CROSS_COMPILE_HOME/usr/lib
export TARGET_LINKFLAGS=$TARGET_LDFLAGS
export AJ_ROOT=$CROSS_COMPILE_HOME/compiled/alljoyn

export JAVA_HOME=$CROSS_COMPILE_HOME/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Likely your best answer will come from someone in the alljoyn community as it's not specific to vanilla SCons, but rather in how SCons is being used by alljoyn build implemented with SCons.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not wrong, you are trying to build AllJoyn on the RaspberryPI and the Pi is an ARM based CPU, so the first correction u need to make is

```
CPU=arm
```

secondly since you are trying to build in Java you need to cross compile
`CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

for a more detailed procedure of extracting on the RaspberryPi [Compiling on the RaspberryPi](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/30cfa7dfb041c12e6ba3) and you can also have a look the [Allseen Alliance Wiki Page](https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/develop/building_and_running)